# Repack the built JAR with maven

Tags: java, maven

What is the easiest way to **repack** a **JAR** that was built with an external packaging tool?

So I have a tool that compiles and packages a library into a jar (execution is called in prepare-package phase). I want to unzip the jar and repack it again with maven-jar-plugin. What would be the easiest way to do that?

Comment: I doubt that Maven is the tool for this job, I'd rather do this with ANT. Or if this must integrate into an existing Maven build cycle then you could use the ANT runner plugin for Maven.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you'd want to repackage a JAR, unless you want to modify its manifest or add some resources...

Anyway, you could use the [unpack](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html) goal of the `maven-dependency-plugin` to unpack that JAR to a given directory, e.g. the `target/classes` directory containing some other resources of your current project.